# MySQL INSERT INTO doesn't do anything - not even error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `63_Activity` (`username`, `time`) VALUES (`$usernann2`, `$date`)");
```

However, it doesn't do anything. Even when I tried correcting the variables to

```
". $variable ."
```

I checked the variables.

I copied the little line of code from somewhere it works.

The database and tables are existing.

I just thought I had things under control, then that happened -.-

Thank you in advance.

PS: I tried adding or die() - but no error. Nothing.

Comment: Please call mysql_error after your query. Hopefully output show a reason of the problem. More info http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: you're using backticks around literal values, I'm quite sure you would want single quotes there.

Comment: Also, the mysql_* functions in php are **deprecated**, meaning that they will disappear some day in the near future.  Their use in new code is discouraged by the php team.  Switch to PDO and prepared statements, because what you're doing makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @fvi I did use single quotes too. Tried doing that. Sorry for forgetting, it's just to late :) Thank you for the tip about the rest. PDO? Can you explain that?

Comment: Start with the [documentation on the php website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).  There are also tons of tutorials on the web, google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you, friend :) Put an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using Paramaterized queries as in the following example:

```
 <?php

try {
    $usernann2 = "whateverUsernameFits";
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare ( "INSERT INTO 63_Activity (username, time) VALUES (:usernann2, :date)");
    $stmt->bindParam ( ':usernann2', $usernann2 );
    $stmt->bindParam ( ':date', $date );        
    $stmt->execute ();
}catch ( PDOException $e ) 
        {
            throw new Exception ( $this->db->errorInfo () . 'Problem inserting object ' );
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            throw new \Exception ( 'Problem inserting object ' );
        }

        ?>
```

Bound parameters are a staple in preventing SQL Injection attacks.  The exceptions thrown would give you a  clue as to what might be the problem in your query if there is one.  I normally check the query first to make sure it's working with real values. From there it is  a process of elimination.

PS. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet for more information on SQL Injection. You should also be able to find some excellent information and questions here on Stackoverflow regarding SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Values need to be in single quotes (`'`), not backticks (`)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `63_Activity` (`username`, `time`) VALUES ('$usernann2', '$date')");
```

You should also make sure you're sanitizing your inputs, as well as preferably not using the `mysql_` functions in place of `mysqli_`

Comment: So I should preferably use mysqli_ instead? Will it give the exact same output ? :)

Answer (score 0):

try to put the query in a variable and echo it, and see if anything wrong, try to run it on php my admin also

Comment: I already did. They work perfectly. I also tried non-variables.

Comment: can you post its echo and also the type of field 'time' ?

Comment: No field. It should input variable $date which echoed "time()"
No problem there. :)

Comment: I assume also that you can see errors: ini_set('display_errors','On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);